# Sticky button on one page

Tags: css, wordpress, position, fixed

I want to have a button having a *fixed position*, but just on that page! I have a one page theme on wordpress and I made myself a button (an arrow that moves up and down when hovered, and always moves when you're on mobile, just slightly).

The first page is mainly a picture, and I want the button to be slightly off from the bottom, I figured how to place it exactly where I want it on desktop and portrait-mobile, but I want it to **scroll along on landscape view**, as it's just bugging to see the button in the middle of the picture.

```
.button {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px 55px;
...


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px max-width: 568px) {
.dark .button { 
position:relative;
bottom: -120px;
text-indent:-9999px;
border:none !important;
background: url('../images/down_arrow.png') no-repeat center center;
```

I also saw that on bigger displays, the position of the button wasn't the same as on my screen (15" shows way different than 27").

Comment: I have seen media queries with multiple conditions separated by comma or joined with an `and`, but it is the first time that I see a media query with two rules inside the parenthesis. Are you sure that is correct?

Answer (score 0):

its hard to surmise your issue on that little information.

have you tried

```
position:absolute;
```

as that its viewport specific as opposed to *relative* which is refers to elements within a parent.

ideally supply a url for us to get the bigger picture.